How to use "DebuggerDisplay" to include object summary in error messages
I have a class (MyData) with several properties (A, B, C). The class does not have an overridden ToString and it cannot have one for other reasons, but it has a method ToDebugString() that is also configured as "debugger display" using.
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToDebugString()}")]
public class MyData {
  public string A {get;set;}
  public string B {get;set;}
  public string C {get;set;}
  public string ToDebugString() => $"{A}-{B}-{C}";
}

I have an assertion for a list of such objects, like this:
var items = new MyData[] { ... };
items.Should().Contain(i => i.A == "foo");

When it fails, it shows an error message like:
Expected items 
{
    MyProject.MyData
    {
        A = "a1", 
        B = "b1", 
        C = "c1"
    }
} to have an item matching (i.A == "foo"). (0.2s)

That is pretty verbose especially if you have many items in the list.
When I define a ToString method, it is used by FluentAssertions and the output is much more condensed, but I cannot do that for the class.
My question is how could I configure FluentAssertions to use my ToDebugString method to log the objects or is there a way to generally use the method that is configured as DebuggerDisplay?

Maybe a formatter will do that: https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/#rendering-objects-with-beauty

Based on the suggestion of @rene, I made a simple custom value formatter that calls the ToDebugString method if it is provided. Of course it would be even better if it would evaluate the expression provided in [DebuggerDisplay], but I could not find such evaluator in the core .NET (probably it is implemented in the debugger), and writing one for my own was beyond my goals now.
If anyone is interested, here is the class I use:
public class DebuggerDisplayFormatter : IValueFormatter
{
    private MethodInfo GetDebugMethod(object value)
    {
        return value?.GetType().GetMethod("ToDebugString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
    }

    public bool CanHandle(object value)
    {
        return GetDebugMethod(value) != null;
    }

    public void Format(object value, FormattedObjectGraph formattedGraph, FormattingContext context, FormatChild formatChild)
    {
        var debugMethod = GetDebugMethod(value);
        var result = debugMethod?.Invoke(value, Array.Empty<object>()) as string;
        formattedGraph.AddFragment(result ?? value.GetType().Name);
    }
}

